# ¿Como enviar datos de una tabla html en nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

estoy tratando de enviar datos de una tabla usando jquery para sacar los valores de la tabla pero no se enviarlos por metodo POST en node js, por el momento solo los muestro en un alert, como los paso del jquery a un app.post('/enviar_datos');.

```
$("#btnEnviarDatos").click(function () {
$("#datatable-responsive tbody tr").each(function (index) {
    var campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6, campo7, campo8, campo9;
    $(this).children("td").each(function (index2) {
        switch (index2) {
            case 1:
            campo1 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.fecha = campo1;
            break;
            case 2:
            campo2 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.categoria = campo2;
            break;
            case 3:
            campo3 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.numfactura = campo3;
            break;
            case 4:
            campo4 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.entregado = campo4;
            break;
            case 5:
            campo5 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.cargado = campo5;
            break;
            case 6:
            campo6 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.empresa = campo6;
            break;
            case 7:
            campo7 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.proveedor = campo7;
            break;
            case 8:
            campo8 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.valor = campo8;
            break;
            case 9:
            campo9 = $(this).text();
            JsonTabla.retencion = campo9;
            break;
        }
    });
    if(campo1!=undefined && campo2!=undefined && campo3!=undefined && campo4!=undefined && campo5!=undefined && campo6!=undefined && campo7!=undefined && campo8!=undefined && campo9!=undefined){
        alert(''+campo1 + ' - ' + campo2 + ' - ' + campo3+ ' - ' + campo4+ ' - ' + campo5+ ' - ' + campo6+ ' - ' + campo7+ ' - ' + campo8 + ' - ' + campo9);

    }         
});
```

});

Comment: A modo de clarificación: lo que quieres es mandar los datos que has sacado usando JQuery hacia un servidor de Node? o símplemente quieres mandar esos datos a cualquier servidor? Lo digo porque lo que normalmente se hace es enviar "desde JQuery hasta Node" y ya el servidor de Node hace lo que sea con los datos.

Comment: Aja quiero enviar esos datos al servidor node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es:

- Mandar por POST el contenido utilizando jQuery.post() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ Podrías hacer algo como
- Desde el servidor de Node crear un endpoint que reciba datos desde el protocolo POST de HTTP y que los procese. ya el cómo depende de qué frameworks y bibliotecas de Node usas en el servidor. Por ejemplo, utilizando Express se hace así:http://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html